# Observable.forkJoin of Angular Route Params Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my Angular component `ngOnInit()` I want to:

1. Read route parameter and execute a dependent HTTP call with it as argument.
2. Execute separate HTTP call.
3. Wait for both HTTP calls to finish.

Both HTTP calls are always executing, but when my first observable is wired up to `route.params`, the `forkJoin(...).subscribe(...)` method never runs. If I replace `this.route.params` with `Observable.of({id: 1234})` `forkJoin().subscribe()` gets called properly.

```
// VERSION 1 forkJoin().subscribe() never gets called
var dependentObservable = this.route.params
    .switchMap(params => {
        this.myId = +params['id'];
        return this.myService.getMyInfo(this.myId);
    });

// VERSION 2 forkJoin().subscribe gets called
var dependentObservable = Observable.of({id: 123})
    .switchMap(params => {
        this.myId = +params['id'];
        return this.myService.getMyInfo(this.myId);
    });

var independentObservable = this.myService.getOtherInfo();

Observable.forkJoin([dependentObservable, independentObservable])
    .subscribe(
        results = { ... },
        error => { ... },
        () => { ... }
    );
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

My guess is `route.params` is never completed. That's why `forkJoin` does not work. You can use `combineLatest` instead of `forkJoin`

Comment: Why it is never completed?

Comment: Because routes can change.

Answer (score 10):

According to this [doc](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) forkJoin emit the last value from each observables, when all observables **completed**.

```
Observable.of({id: 123})
```

will be compleated immediately after giving {id: 123}

But

```
this.route.params
```

Will never be completed. Since route params can be changed by a user when he edits browser address bar. This changes will be never stopped.

I think you can complete observable using take(1):

```
 this.route.params.take(1)
```

Or, If you want to be responsive to changing of route params use combineLatest

```
Observable.combineLatest(dependentObservable, independentObservable)
```